'It' or 'that' pronouns in why- questions
In the dialogue below:
Person A: My trip was stressful.
Person B: Why was it?
I feel like "why was it?" sounds wrong and "why was that?" sounds correct and more natural in casual spoken English (with the stress and a rising-falling tone on 'that') but I can't explain why. Is "why was it?" actually wrong? And if so, why is "why was that?" correct. Can someone explain the grammar to me?
Thanks

Sometimes, 'padding' makes a string far more idiomatic. << Person A: My trip was stressful. Person B: Why was it stressful? >> sounds fine. I believe that deleting the adjective leaves a weak ending, rather as with << I'm taller than he's. >>  But finding references to this sort of idiomatic constraint will be difficult.


I feel like "why was it?" sounds wrong and "why was that?" sounds correct.

Both are possible – context is king: it puts the emphasis on “trip”; that focuses on, and is a reaction to, A’s emotional statement.
Context: B has arranged a business trip for A. After the trip, A approaches B:
Person A: My trip was stressful.
Person B: Why was it? -> Which of the arrangements that I made caused the stress?
Context: A arrives home
A: My trip was stressful.
Person B: Why was that? -> Why was that (=what you have just said) the case? -> What was the reason for/cause of your trip being stressful?

I agree with OP that 'Why was it?' sounds unnatural.

@EdwinAshworth - try altering the tone of B in the first example to one of disappointed concern.

Yes; I'd tried various intonations (note the stress in the suggested alternative in the comment after the question). I still feel that an undeleted or rephrased version is far more idiomatic.

@EdwinAshworth I feel more generous toward it, but if something's off, perhaps it's that as long as one is shortening, the most likely response is simply "Why?"

@EdwinAshworth Try adding an implied word: “Why was it [stressful]?”

@gidds That'sjust it. I would add the word, and not delete it, and I believe that's customary.

Thank you all, very helpful
